# Why would the residuals from these two models result in the wrong AIC being calculated?

Tags: regression, modeling, residuals, aic

We run two linear regressions, Model 1 and Model 2. The residuals from these two models are plotted against the predicted values. If I understand correctly, the AIC from these two models would be 'incorrect'.

Can anyone give an intuitive, non-mathematical explanation why the AIC from these two models would be incorrect?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the models are estimated by maximum likelihood and the likelihood values are used in calculating AICs, the question reduces to whether the estimated likelihoods of the two models will be correct (I assume there is no problem calculating the number of parameters -- the other component of AIC).

If the likelihood function assumes the residuals to be independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) over the whole sample, this assumption will be violated in model 1, so likelihood value (and AIC value) will be incorrect there. Meanwhile, it is not so obvious with model 2 as the residuals might come from a skewed distribution but still be i.i.d. so that the likelihood value (and the AIC value) would be correct.

If the likelihood function assumes something else than i.i.d. residuals and happens to guess the distributions of residuals right (along the lines of the comment by @CagdasOzgenc), even model 1 (let alone model 2) might have a correct likelihood value (and correct AIC value). However, how often do you assume a distribution of residuals compatible with what we see in plot 1? Not very often, I guess...

Comment: I think the question assumes that all models have symmetric and spherical residuals. When modeled like that obviously one will have incorrect likelihoods. For model 1, the model needs to support the nonspherical variance, in the second one possibly an additional parameters to deal with asymmetry. IID is not a requirement. Log-likelihood will not be a simple sum in non-IID case, that's it.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc: Good, enlightening comment. Should I change something in the answer, or will your comment suffice? Since I do not really claim that i.i.d. is necessary (I discuss it in the last paragraph).

Comment: I think the question is well covered by your answer. I just provided some small add-on details. I work with likelihoods of non-iid and asymmetric cases all the time. But as you pointed out they were never so nice looking like above.

Comment: @CagdasOzgen But for AIC to work don't you need the same distributional assumptions (of the disturbances) in both models?..otherwise it seems like comparing apples to oranges because you would have two very different likelihood functions.

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld, Isn't the beauty of AIC that it can compare any two models as long as the dependent variable is the same? I think you actually *can* compare apples to oranges using AIC.

Comment: @RichardHardy My understanding (and I may be wrong) is that the advantage of AIC over Wald, Likelihood ratio tests and alike is the ability to compare non-nested models.  However the kernel of the likelihood function (the distributional assumptions on the disturbance terms) should remain constant as the penalization of the number of parameters is taken in respect to such an argument. When distributional assumptions change across models I would think something along the lines of a Housman test more appropriate.

Comment: @RichardHardy One example is a truncated regression model.  Consider data that has been truncated.  Run an OLS model than the corrected truncated model.  The OLS will win AIC wise, but the OLS may be very bias (because it made an incorrect distributional assumption) and a housman test could reveal this fact when the bias is significant relative to efficiency loss.  So the truncated model could be preferred while AIC fails to acknowledge  it.

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld. AIC will not work if the data is modified in any way while comparing models. All models should be estimated over the same data set. There is no apples to oranges comparison. The entropy of data is ignored in AIC, because it is assumed to be the same no matter the model. When data is modified this assumption doesn't hold.

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld, I am not completely sure about this myself... Could it be the case that OLS will truly be better in terms of whatever AIC tries to maximize? Perhaps OLS will give smaller MSE even though it will not be a "correct model" (recall the bias-variance trade-off). So then the question is, what do you care about: accurate forecasts or detecting the "true" model (even if the latter will be estimated pretty imprecisely given the available data). In other words, are you willing to increase variance a lot just to avoid bias.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc, to clarify matters: can you confirm (or deny) that AIC can legitimately be used to compare any two models as long as the dependent variable is the same? Or if I am missing something, what is the correct version of this statement?

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc the data is not modified between models in my truncated example, only the distributional assumptions on the disturbances.